# tycho - Error assembling JAR: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven, build, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am adding maven/tycho build to [open-source Markdown Editor eclipse-plugin project](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/Eclipse-Markdown-Editor-Plugin)

I did what I did for several other projects: adding pom.xml for parent, plugin and feature projects. (Sources reference is above, typical pom.xml is below)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.winterwell.markdown</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>winterwell.markdown</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.3</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

    <name>markdown-editor</name>
    <description>Markdown Editor Plugin for Eclipse</description>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    </build>


</project>
```

However `mvn package` give somewhat irrelevant error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.18.1:package-plugin (default-package-plugin)  on project winterwell.markdown: Error assembling JAR: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]

There is no definitions for any zip files.

A looked carefully at project and the only difference I see I that it has some .jar dependencies in lib folder.

[image]

**What the real problem with maven/tycho build could be?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was just to exclude `target/,\` from build.properties

```
source.. = src/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/,\
               .,\
               lib/
```